# Magento 1.6.1 Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '104187/14' for key 'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_INVOICE_INCREMENT_ID''

Tags: mysql, magento, zend-framework, pdo, magento-1.6

I've a problem with a e-commerce site developed with Magento 1.6.1

I noticed that when two orders are placed at the same time I get the following exception:

This exception prevents the saving of the order and the order is not placed correctly.

The exception occurs only when two orders are simultaneous or close in time (just 1.2 seconds). It seems so much a problem of concurrency in the database.

When orders are spaced in time everything is working correctly.

Somebody has happened something like this? Does anyone have any idea? Thank you very much for your cooperation.

Ivano

This is my stacktrace:

```
2014-09-18T09:14:43+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '104187/14' for key 'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_INVOICE_INCREMENT_ID'' in /opt/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /opt/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /opt/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /opt/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /opt/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#5 /opt/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#6 /opt/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(574): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#7 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(448): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('sales_flat_invo...', Array)
#8 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Abstract.php(425): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice))
#9 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice))
#10 /opt/magento/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(2149): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#11 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(319): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_afterSave()
#12 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#13 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(105): call_user_func(Array)
#14 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(159): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->_runCallbacks()
#15 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(189): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
#16 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#17 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php(523): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#18 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php(267): Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout->place('EC-9B092584H406...')
#19 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Paypal_Controller_Express_Abstract->placeOrderAction()
#20 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(253): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('placeOrder')
#21 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#22 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#23 /opt/magento/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#24 /opt/magento/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#25 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '104187/14' for key 'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_INVOICE_INCREMENT_ID'' in /opt/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /opt/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /opt/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /opt/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#4 /opt/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#5 /opt/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(574): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#6 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(448): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('sales_flat_invo...', Array)
#7 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Abstract.php(425): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice))
#8 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice))
#9 /opt/magento/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(2149): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#10 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(319): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_afterSave()
#11 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#12 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(105): call_user_func(Array)
#13 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(159): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->_runCallbacks()
#14 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(189): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
#15 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#16 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php(523): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#17 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php(267): Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout->place('EC-9B092584H406...')
#18 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Paypal_Controller_Express_Abstract->placeOrderAction()
#19 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(253): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('placeOrder')
#20 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#21 /opt/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#22 /opt/magento/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#23 /opt/magento/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#24 {main}
```

Comment: Is the order number based on the time of day? That seems like an extraordinarily bad plan. You'll need to use higher precision than a second if that's the case, or use a [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

Comment: Hi tadman. Thanks. No, I use the increment id policy of Magento.